# Convert Excel to csv UTF-8 script issue

Tags: powershell

So something very weird is happening to me and I am unable to find the resolution for this.
I have a script that converts excel to csv UTF-8 file which goes like this:

```
$root = "D:\Users\ashish.sinha\Downloads\Trail Overview"
#open excel object and get excel name

$excel = new-object -comobject excel.application

$excel.Visible=$True

$excel.DisplayAlerts = $False

$excelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $root -FIlter *.xlsx

$workbook = $excel.workbooks.open($excelFiles.FullName)

$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.item(1)


$csvName = $excelFiles.FullName -replace 'xlsx','csv'

$worksheet.SaveAs($csvName,6)

$workbook.save()

$workbook.close()

$excel.quit()
```

When i run this code in parts like first 5-6 lines it works but when i run the full code(not saving it just F5) then i get the error like this:

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800AC472
At line:14 char:1
+ $worksheet.SaveAs($csvName,6)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

Can someone please help?

Thanks,
Ashish

Comment: Please read [this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and also be more specific. Like, what IDE are you using? PowerShell ISE? Visual Studio Code? Have you googled the error? What did you find?

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` probably returns an array of files (or even perhaps folders, as you didn't specify switch `-File`. Method `$excel.workbooks.open` cannot handle an array of files. Also, to save as csv in UTF-8 you need value 62 (xlCSVUTF8), not 6 (xlCSV). See [XlFileFormat enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat)

Comment: @theo thanks for your input. I will change the code to 62. Also I have kept only one file in the directory. The issue is when i run the codes in part i get what i want but when irun the full code it gives error.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: So its written like this in About Excel Microsoft 365 MSO 16.0.***.*** 64 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Excel up to version 2016, there is no way to convert an xlsx sheet to a UTF-8 encoded csv file built in.
My earlier comment about a format specifier `xlCSVUTF8` is for later versions I guess (the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat) do not reveal at what point Microsoft implemented that constant..)

So, to convert to UTF-8 csv file, I have created this function:

```
function Convert-ExcelToCsv {
    # converts a worksheet from .xsl and .xslx files to Csv files in UTF-8 encoding
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf})]
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [Alias("FilePath", "FullName")]
        [string[]]$Path,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [int]$SheetNumber = 1,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [char]$Delimiter = ','

    )
    begin {
        try {
            $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application -ErrorAction Stop -Verbose:$false
            $excel.Visible = $false 
            $excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
        }
        catch { 
            throw "This function needs Microsoft Excel to be installed." 
        }
    }

    process {
        foreach ($xlFile in $Path) {
            Write-Verbose "Processing '$xlFile'"
            # convert Excel file to CSV file UTF-8
            $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($xlFile)

            # set the active worksheet
            if ($SheetNumber -notin 1..@($workbook.Sheets).Count) { $SheetNumber = 1 }
            $workbook.Worksheets.Item($SheetNumber).Activate()

            # Unfortunately, Excel up to and including version 2016 has no option to export csv format in UTF8 encoding 
            # so we save as 'Unicode Text (*.txt)' (= Tab delimited)
            # See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas.aspx

            # Apparently, at some point (version 2019?) there is a new format specifier called xlCSVUTF8 (value 62),
            # but I can't find anywhere as of which version this is a valid value. It certainly doesn't exist in 
            # versions up to and including version 2016.
            # see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat

            # create a temporary file to store the in-between result
            $tempFile = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension([System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName(), ".txt")
            if (Test-Path -Path $tempFile -PathType Leaf) { Remove-Item -Path $tempFile -Force }

            $xlUnicodeText = 42         # Tab-delimited. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241279.aspx
            $workbook.SaveAs($tempFile, $xlUnicodeText) 
            $workbook.Saved = $true
            $workbook.Close()

            # now import, delete the temp file and save as Csv in UTF-8 encoding
            $result = Import-Csv -Path $tempFile -Encoding Unicode -Delimiter "`t" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
            Remove-Item -Path $tempFile -Force
            $csvFile = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($xlFile, ".csv")
            Write-Verbose "Creating '$csvFile'"
            $result | Export-Csv -Path $csvFile -Delimiter $Delimiter -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation -Force
        }
    }

    end {
        Write-Verbose "Quit and cleanup"
        $excel.Quit()

        # cleanup COM objects
        [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook) | Out-Null
        [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel) | Out-Null
        [System.GC]::Collect()
        [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    }
}
```

With this function in place at the top of your script, you can use it like

```
$root = "D:\Users\ashish.sinha\Downloads\Trail Overview"
Get-ChildItem -Path $root -Filter '*.xlsx' | Convert-ExcelToCsv -Verbose
```

<sup>Leave out switch `-Verbose` if you do not wish to see informative messages on screen</sup>

Comment: Thanks @Theo. I accepted your answer. I though i did before. Thanks for all your help. Actually to be honest i have been using stack overflow for quite long time but I am mostly able to find solutions. This was the 2nd question i posted in past 4 years :). Appreciate it .