# Define AD Account Expiry Date Time and AD groups for Bulk AD Account Creation via CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv, automation, get-aduser

I have a script which automates bulk AD account creations.

The script works fine but when I try to define account expiry date and time for each user (-AccountExpirationDate) it fails.

The script is as follows:

```
# Store the data from NewUsersFinal.csv in the $ADUsers variable
$ADUsers = Import-Csv C:\temp\NewUsersSent.csv

# Define UPN
$UPN = "my.domain.net"

# Loop through each row containing user details in the CSV file
foreach ($User in $ADUsers) {

    #Read user data from each field in each row and assign the data to a variable as below
    $username = $User.username
    $password = $User.password
    $firstname = $User.firstname
    $lastname = $User.lastname
    $OU = $User.ou #This field refers to the OU the user account is to be created in
    $email = $User.email
    $telephone = $User.telephone
    $jobtitle = $User.jobtitle
    $accountexpires = $User.accountexpires

    # Check to see if the user already exists in AD
    if (Get-ADUser -F { SamAccountName -eq $username }) {
        
        # If user does exist, give a warning
        Write-Warning "A user account with username $username already exists in Active Directory."
    }
    else {

        # User does not exist then proceed to create the new user account
        # Account will be created in the OU provided by the $OU variable read from the CSV file
        New-ADUser `
            -SamAccountName $username `
            -UserPrincipalName "$username@$UPN" `
            -Name "$firstname $lastname" `
            -GivenName $firstname `
            -Surname $lastname `
            -Enabled $True `
            -DisplayName "$lastname, $firstname" `
            -Path $OU `
            -OfficePhone $telephone `
            -MobilePhone $telephone `
            -HomePhone $telephone `
            -EmailAddress $email `
            -Description $jobtitle `
            -AccountExpirationDate $accountexpires `
            -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-secureString $password -AsPlainText -Force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $False -PasswordNeverExpires $True

        # If user is created, show message.
        Write-Host "The user account $username is created." -ForegroundColor Cyan
    }
}
```

The CSV file is below:

[image: CSV File Format]

When I run the code I get the following errors (the account don't actually get created):

```
New-ADUser : Cannot bind parameter 'AccountExpirationDate'. Cannot convert value ""11/17/2023 2:22:48 PM"" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized 
as a valid DateTime."
At C:\Users\Me\Desktop\BulkNewUsers.ps1:45 char:36
+             -AccountExpirationDate $accountexpires `
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser

The user account TTesting1 is created.
New-ADUser : Cannot bind parameter 'AccountExpirationDate'. Cannot convert value "0" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At C:\Users\Me\Desktop\BulkNewUsers.ps1:45 char:36
+             -AccountExpirationDate $accountexpires `
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser

The user account TTesting2 is created.
Press Enter to exit:
```

Seems like PS is not accepting my date time format.

I have tried to read up from the following sites:

https://ss64.com/ps/new-aduser.html

https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-dateformats.html

I believe I need to specify format pattern for PS to accept my date time in the CSV.

I have also read that stating "0" sets the account not to expire - could this be clarified?

I was also wondering if it is also possible to define AD groups to be added into the CSV to add new users too with using ; as delimiter to each AD group name? - I believe I may need to incorporate Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership into the script.

**UPDATE 1**

Thanks Theo ran you script executed with no error BUT the account expiry was not set:

[image: AD Account Expiry1]

[image: AD Account Expiry2]

Is it because I created these account with previous failed attempts (do I need to wait for 24 hours before attempting to create the account again - cached detail) I did delete the account and forced replication in DCs.

**UPDATE 2**

Theo as requested.

I tried the first suggested code below:

[image: Code Alteration 1]

Got this error code:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> C:\Users\Me\Desktop\BulkNewUsers.ps1
At C:\Users\Me\Desktop\BulkNewUsers.ps1:48 char:67
+     $accountexpires = (Get-Date) ; [datetime]::TryParse(11/17/2023 2:22:48 PM, [ ...
+                                                                   ~
Missing ')' in method call.
At C:\Users\Me\Desktop\BulkNewUsers.ps1:48 char:68
+     $accountexpires = (Get-Date) ; [datetime]::TryParse(11/17/2023 2:22:48 PM, [ ...
+                                                                    ~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '2:22:48' in expression or statement.
At C:\Users\Me\Desktop\BulkNewUsers.ps1:8 char:29
+ foreach ($User in $ADUsers) {
+                             ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block.
At C:\Users\Me\Desktop\BulkNewUsers.ps1:48 char:100
+ ... $accountexpires) {
+                    ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At C:\Users\Me\Desktop\BulkNewUsers.ps1:64 char:1
+ }
+ ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInMethodCall
```

I tried the second suggested code below:

[image: Code Alteration 2]

Got this error code:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> C:\Users\Me\Desktop\BulkNewUsers.ps1
At C:\Users\Me\Desktop\BulkNewUsers.ps1:48 char:72
+     $accountexpires = (Get-Date) ; [datetime]::TryParseExact(11/17/2023 2:22:48  ...
+                                                                        ~
Missing ')' in method call.
At C:\Users\Me\Desktop\BulkNewUsers.ps1:48 char:73
+     $accountexpires = (Get-Date) ; [datetime]::TryParseExact(11/17/2023 2:22:48  ...
+                                                                         ~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '2:22:48' in expression or statement.
At C:\Users\Me\Desktop\BulkNewUsers.ps1:8 char:29
+ foreach ($User in $ADUsers) {
+                             ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block.
At C:\Users\Me\Desktop\BulkNewUsers.ps1:48 char:159
+ ... $accountexpires){
+                    ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At C:\Users\Me\Desktop\BulkNewUsers.ps1:64 char:1
+ }
+ ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInMethodCall
```

Seems like the same error code?

Please see CSV in notepad format below:

```
FirstName,LastName,Username,Email,Password,Telephone,JobTitle,AccountExpires,OU
Test1,Test2,TTesting1,Testing1@email.co.uk,V6DyG3H7a,4.47723E+11,This is a Test 1,11/17/2023 2:22:48 PM,"CN=Users,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=net"
Test3,Test4,TTesting2,Testing2@email.co.uk,438MXn8D5,4.47723E+11,This is a Test 2,0,"CN=Users,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=net"
```

**UPDATE 3**

I did what you asked

```
$accountexpires = (Get-Date)  
[datetime]::TryParseExact('11/17/2023 2:22:48 PM', 'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt', [cultureinfo]'en-US', 'None',[ref]$accountexpires)
```

This returned "true" in PowerShell.

It weird you mentioned the non printing character as we had an issue with copying text from MS SharePoint to Notepad then to AD - which would contain
special hidden characters, to overcome this (being lazy) I instead copied to from MS SharePoint to MS Word then into AD which fixed the special hidden characters (to view the special hidden characters we performed conversion on the text to "ASCII to Hex" then back to "HEX to ASCII" which would display the special hidden characters)

I did what you asked I made the changes in Notepad fields in between double quotes and re-typed the expiry dates and this fixed the issue! Expiry date displaying on newly created users.

Thanks!!!

Now I tried to add AD Groups and it semi failed (I guess to naming conventions of the AD groups which they contain "-" and "_" in there names)

Please see New CSV in notepad format below:

```
FirstName,LastName,Username,Email,Password,Telephone,JobTitle,AccountExpires,OU,ADGroups
"Test1","Test2","TTesting1","Testing1@email.co.uk","V6DyG3H7a","447723000000","This is a Test 1","11/17/2023 2:22:48 PM","CN=Users,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=net","ADGroupName1;AD_Group_Name_2;AD-Group-Name-3;"
"Test3","Test4","TTesting2","Testing2@email.co.uk","438MXn8D5","447723000001","This is a Test 2","0","CN=Users,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=net""ADGroupName1;AD_Group_Name_2;"
```

The code I used below:

```
# Store the data from NewUsersFinal.csv in the $ADUsers variable
$ADUsers = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\NewUsersSent.csv'

# Define UPN
$UPN = "my.domain.net"

# Loop through each row containing user details in the CSV file
foreach ($User in $ADUsers) {
    # Read some user data from each field in each row and assign the data to a variable as below
    $username = $User.username

    # Check to see if the user already exists in AD
    if (Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$username'") {
        # If user does exist, give a warning
        Write-Warning "A user account with username $username already exists in Active Directory."
        continue  # skip this one and proceed with the next user
    }

    # User does not exist then proceed to create the new user account
    # Account will be created in the OU provided by the $OU variable read from the CSV file

    # create some convenience variables from the csv data as these are used more than once
    $firstname      = $User.firstname
    $lastname       = $User.lastname
    $telephone      = $User.telephone

    # create a splatting Hashtable for the New-ADUser cmdlet
    $userParams = @{
        SamAccountName        = $username
        UserPrincipalName     = "$username@$UPN"
        Name                  = "$firstname $lastname"
        GivenName             = $firstname
        Surname               = $lastname
        Enabled               = $true
        DisplayName           = "$lastname, $firstname"
        Path                  = $User.ou
        OfficePhone           = $telephone
        MobilePhone           = $telephone
        HomePhone             = $telephone
        EmailAddress          = $User.email
        Description           = $User.jobtitle
        AccountPassword       = (ConvertTo-secureString $User.password -AsPlainText -Force)
        ChangePasswordAtLogon = $false
        PasswordNeverExpires  = $true
    }

    # see if we can get a valid DateTime from the csv field 'accountexpires'
    $accountexpires = (Get-Date)
    if ([datetime]::TryParseExact($User.accountexpires, 'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt', [cultureinfo]'en-US', 'None',[ref]$accountexpires)) {
        # this user does have an account expiration date, so add it to the Hash
        $userParams['AccountExpirationDate'] = $accountexpires
    }
    # create the user (PassThru makes the cmdlet return the user object just created)
    $newUser = New-ADUser @userParams -PassThru
    Write-Host "The user account $username is created." -ForegroundColor Cyan

    #####################################################################################
    # If you have a field in the CSV where groups are listed the new user should become
    # a member of (as you said, separated by ;), you can add the user to these groups here:
    
    $User.adgroups -split ';' | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' } | ForEach-Object {
         Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ -Members $newUser
     }

}
```

There error messages I got from PS when I tried to run the code with AD groups:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> C:\Users\Me\Desktop\BulkNewUsers.ps1
The user account TTesting1 is created.
New-ADUser : The object name has bad syntax
At C:\Users\Me\Desktop\BulkNewUsers.ps1:54 char:16
+     $newUser = New-ADUser @userParams -PassThru
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=Test3 Test4,...AD_Group_Name_2;:String) [New-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8335,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
 
The user account TTesting2 is created.
```

Weirdly the first account is created but the second is not.

Do I have also have to define `Groups = $User.ADGroups` in `$userParams` part of the code?

**UPDATE 4**

Theo I figured out the issue in UPDATE 3 is was a "," was not defined between double quotations of the OU field and the AD Group field for the 2nd user in the CSV file:

`"CN=Users,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=net""ADGroupName1;AD_Group_Name_2;"`

Changed to:

`"CN=Users,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=net","ADGroupName1;AD_Group_Name_2;"`

This resolved the issue!

Comment: When testing the value from your CSV, you must of course enclose it in between quotes. These .Net methods require a **string**.. so `[datetime]::TryParse('11/17/2023 2:22:48 PM', [ref]$accountexpires)` and `[datetime]::TryParseExact('11/17/2023 2:22:48 PM', 'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt', [cultureinfo]'en-US', 'None',[ref]$accountexpires)`. However, in the csv example you posted, I could see there is a non-printing character in between `20` and `23`. My code works and should also work for you if you get your CSV right...

Comment: ... Constantly opening and re-saving using Excel destroys it completely. Use Notepad and put all your fields in between double quotes like you do on the `OU` field. Retype **all** the date fields to make sure no invisible characters get inserted there.

Comment: Theo thanks again sir!!!! You are the man!! Always helpful!!! Please ignore Update 3 which was resolved in Update 4 - being lazy and not reading the error output!

Comment: The error says the date has extra quotes.

Comment: @js2010 I didn't notice that but the 2nd expiry date was "0" - which is set not to expire and this wasn't accepted and stated - Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." Which may have given the same error if the quotes were removed, unfortunately I can't test as the code has now been resolved with the big help of Theo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that when a user should be created with an account that never expires, the `AccountExpirationDate` should not be set.
Otherwise, a valid DateTime object should be used to set the expiration date and time. (if no time is specified, the time is assumed to 12:00:00 AM local time.)

Your code uses the nasty backticks to separate the parameters for New-ADUser each on a new line, but a far better approach is to use [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) on cmdlets that take a lot of parameters.
That way, the code is easy to read/maintain, PLUS you can either add of omit certain parameters based on a condition like in this case the `AccountExpirationDate`.

Please also read the commented code at the bottom to show how you can add the new user to groups too.

```
# Store the data from NewUsersFinal.csv in the $ADUsers variable
$ADUsers = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\NewUsersSent.csv'

# Define UPN
$UPN = "my.domain.net"

# Loop through each row containing user details in the CSV file
foreach ($User in $ADUsers) {
    # Read some user data from each field in each row and assign the data to a variable as below
    $username = $User.username

    # Check to see if the user already exists in AD
    if (Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$username'") {
        # If user does exist, give a warning
        Write-Warning "A user account with username $username already exists in Active Directory."
        continue  # skip this one and proceed with the next user
    }

    # User does not exist then proceed to create the new user account
    # Account will be created in the OU provided by the $OU variable read from the CSV file

    # create some convenience variables from the csv data as these are used more than once
    $firstname      = $User.firstname
    $lastname       = $User.lastname
    $telephone      = $User.telephone

    # create a splatting Hashtable for the New-ADUser cmdlet
    $userParams = @{
        SamAccountName        = $username
        UserPrincipalName     = "$username@$UPN"
        Name                  = "$firstname $lastname"
        GivenName             = $firstname
        Surname               = $lastname
        Enabled               = $true
        DisplayName           = "$lastname, $firstname"
        Path                  = $User.ou
        OfficePhone           = $telephone
        MobilePhone           = $telephone
        HomePhone             = $telephone
        EmailAddress          = $User.email
        Description           = $User.jobtitle
        AccountPassword       = (ConvertTo-secureString $User.password -AsPlainText -Force)
        ChangePasswordAtLogon = $false
        PasswordNeverExpires  = $true
    }

    # see if we can get a valid DateTime from the csv field 'accountexpires'
    $accountexpires = (Get-Date)
    if ([datetime]::TryParse($User.accountexpires, [ref]$accountexpires)) {
        # this user does have an account expiration date, so add it to the Hash
        $userParams['AccountExpirationDate'] = $accountexpires
    }
    # create the user (PassThru makes the cmdlet return the user object just created)
    $newUser = New-ADUser @userParams -PassThru
    Write-Host "The user account $username is created." -ForegroundColor Cyan

    #####################################################################################
    # If you have a field in the CSV where groups are listed the new user should become
    # a member of (as you said, separated by ;), you can add the user to these groups here:

    # $User.groups -split ';' | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' } | ForEach-Object {
    #     Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ -Members $newUser
    # }

}
```

---

Instead of `[datetime]::TryParse()` you can also use the `[datetime]::TryParseExact()` method, depending on how you formatted the dates in your csv file.

If you do use this English 12-hour clock format, `[datetime]::TryParseExact($User.accountexpires, 'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt', [cultureinfo]'en-US', 'None',[ref]$accountexpires)` works.

You can test this in Powershell easily with

```
$accountexpires = (Get-Date)  
[datetime]::TryParseExact('11/17/2023 2:22:48 PM', 'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt', [cultureinfo]'en-US', 'None',[ref]$accountexpires)
```

which should return `True`

If this returns `False`, you either mismatched the date pattern, or (as in your example) the date string got screwed-up somehow by invisible control characters. In that case, manually retype the date and test again.

Comment: Thanks @Theo I will attempt run the code (that has been commented out) for the AD groups after I get setting expiry date for the users. Please see my update 1 above.

Comment: @S.Mahmood That would mean `[datetime]::TryParse($User.accountexpires, [ref]$accountexpires)` does not recognize the date format from the csv. Please test this on some of those values. It sort-of looks like you have added extra quotes around the dates in the csv??

Comment: @S.Mahmood Try in the PowerShell console this: `$accountexpires = (Get-Date) ; [datetime]::TryParse(<value copy/pasted from csv>, [ref]$accountexpires)`

If that returns False, you have a different format in the csv than what you showed, or extra characters are in there too.

Also try: `$accountexpires = (Get-Date) ; [datetime]::TryParseExact(<value copy/pasted from csv>, 'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt', [cultureinfo]'en-US', 'None',[ref]$accountexpires)` 

Please open the csv in notepad, copy the first 3 or 4 lines, edit your post and paste that in there as **TEXT** not as image.

Comment: Theo sorry for the late response I tried to put my update on yesterday around 19:30 got an message stating to many edit in Stack overflow. Anyways I put the Update 2 above - like you said seems like my date format is not being accepted. I have also realised I put 'PM' in my date when my date is 24 hour format.

Comment: @S.Mahmood Ok then you need to think of the format you are going to use in the csv and be consequent in using that format. Only then can we make sure the date is recognized in the code. Also, in what you posted I can see the telephone numbers are screwed up be Excel and are now numbers in scientific format...

Comment: Theo yes happy to proceed which ever format you think is best - I only got the date and time style from this site https://ss64.com/ps/new-aduser.html - please advise how to proceed (if you could change you code to work in the current date/time formant), yes I keep changing the telephone fields to text from scientific fields but it keeps reverting (pain in the backside) but still in scientific format the telephones appears in the fields correctly in AD.

Comment: I didn't see you added the information below the code you provided sorry it was helpful. I have no managed to get the code working! Thanks for taking the time to get it sorted. I do have one last question do I have to update the CSV only in notepad? As I am planning on sending out the CSV to be filled out by users managers (apart from password, account expiry and OU fields)

Comment: @S.Mahmood Thanks for the feedback. Glad to hear it is working for you now. You can of course have your managers to fill in the details in Excel, but then remember that Excel can change the data as you can see with the telephone numbers Do they send xlsx files back to you? In that case, make sure then you mark all columns as TEXT before having Excel export as csv.  What I meant with you using notepad was that while working on the code you should not rely on the output of Excel because weird things can happen then (number formats, encoding etc..)

Comment: @S.Mahmood If you do run into encoding problems with the excel files the managers send back to you (like the exported csv should be in UTF-8), you can use function [Convert-ExcelToCsv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64591451/9898643) I wrote some time ago

Comment: thanks once again Theo I will send as xlsx and mark all columns as text then once received and information added from my side I will export as CSV, if that doesn't work I will use your function.